# Distinct vs Group by in count validation

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I give

```
select count(*) from <table>;
```

it gives around 100 000 records

But when I given

```
select count(*) from(select distinct col1,col2,col3... from <table>)c
```

it gives around 75 000 records

I thought there are lot of duplicate records in that table.So I decided to give find out  duplicate using

```
select col1,col2,col3...count(*) from <table> group by col1,col2,col3...
Having count(*)>1
```

It gives zero records

That means no duplicate records found . It looks contradictory I am curious to know what is happening in ...

Comment: You would appear to be misunderstanding the results.  Your queries are clearly not the actual queries you are running, so I would first guess a typo in the queries -- such as different sets of columns.

Comment: Yes sorry I included select distinct in Having count(*)>1 query

Comment: it means that the columns that you are querying have duplicates and the columns you are not querying in the sub-query are the ones that make those rows "unique"